# I cant seem to get document.cookie domain working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create my website and basically I want to make a cookie on the admin site that is created on the www site. I'm doing `document.cookie('loggedIn=true; domain=www.(mysite).co')` here's the script:

```
  <script>
    const password = 'Admin';

    if (window.location.href.includes('?pass='+password)) {
        document.cookie = 'loggedIn=true; domain=www.(mysite).co';
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: No there are no errors showing, i just need support

Comment: i needed support i dont know how to fix it, its not doing what i want it to do, its not creating the cookie at the main site.

Comment: For anyone to be able to help you, we need more details. What is not happening that you think should happen, how do you know it's not happening, and why do you expect it to? You can't email your mechanic and say just, "My car is not running like I want."

Comment: bascly i want to create a cookie and store it to another site so basicly you press sign in as admin on the main site and you type in the password on the 2nd site then it will store a cookie to the main site and it will replace the sign in as admin button with admin dashboard button if the cookie is valid.

Comment: i want to store a cookie on another site but the code is on a other site.

Comment: Cookies are not stored on a site, they are stored by the user agent (browser). If the sites are in completely different domains, a standard cookie set by a request in one will not be visible in the other. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie

Comment: ok thanks, how am i going to make this work then?

Comment: is there a nother way i can store info so its accessable to a nother domain?

Comment: There's a whole industry around securely sharing authentication and authorization across the web, but none of them can be summarized in a line of code. Either rethink what your'e trying to do, or accept the fact that you're going to be a while studying this. :)

Comment: ummmm ok thank you

Comment: i know, i could just make it redirect you to www.(mysite).com then have something like "?PassCorrect" then if it detects that it changes it/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there's no actual way to do this, you can have a system where it redirects you to the main site and you have something like: ?CorrectPass and if it detects that in the url with javascript it does something.